# Getting Null returned for some portion of soapUI property transfer

Tags: xml, soapui, xml-namespaces

I am getting null returned for properties in a particular element. Any attribute or node value i try to transfer in "NDCMSG_Payload" tag is giving null . I am able to transfer property in NDCMSG_Header tag . I am hoping someone will spot the problem.

The property transfer code with namespace is:

```
declare namespace soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
declare namespace ns2="http://sita.aero/NDC/NDCUtility/v1";
declare namespace xmlns="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST/2017.2";
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns2:NDCMSG_Envelope/NDCMSG_Body/NDCMSG_Payload/OrderViewRS/Document

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:NDCMSG_Envelope xmlns:ns2="http://sita.aero/NDC/NDCUtility/v1">
         <NDCMSG_Header>              
            <MessageId>ID-1548230775813-0-48297-2</MessageId>
         </NDCMSG_Header>
         <NDCMSG_Body>
            <NDCMSG_Payload>
               <OrderViewRS PrimaryLangID="en" Target="Test" TimeStamp="2019-02-15T11:05:12.305+00:00" Version="16.23" xmlns="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST/2017.2">
                  <Document id="PGU8NA">
                     <Name>Air Canada</Name>
                     <ReferenceVersion>UAT-OTA-2010B</ReferenceVersion>
                  </Document>
            </NDCMSG_Payload>
         </NDCMSG_Body>
      </ns2:NDCMSG_Envelope>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Your XML is invalid. You open the OrderViewRS tag, but you never close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the OrderViewRS, that declares a generic namespace:

```
xmlns="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST/2017.2"
```

In your xpath it is declared, but you also have elements at a higher level, that is not in that namespace. When I give this namespace a specific name, and add that namespace to the tags on that level and deeper, the xpath works as intended.

```
declare namespace soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
declare namespace ns2="http://sita.aero/NDC/NDCUtility/v1";
declare namespace ns3="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST/2017.2";
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns2:NDCMSG_Envelope/NDCMSG_Body/NDCMSG_Payload/ns3:OrderViewRS/ns3:Document/ns3:Name

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:NDCMSG_Envelope xmlns:ns2="http://sita.aero/NDC/NDCUtility/v1">
         <NDCMSG_Header>              
            <MessageId>ID-1548230775813-0-48297-2</MessageId>
         </NDCMSG_Header>
         <NDCMSG_Body>
            <NDCMSG_Payload>
               <ns3:OrderViewRS PrimaryLangID="en" Target="Test" TimeStamp="2019-02-15T11:05:12.305+00:00" Version="16.23" xmlns:ns3="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST/2017.2">
                  <ns3:Document id="PGU8NA">
                     <ns3:Name>Air Canada</ns3:Name>
                     <ns3:ReferenceVersion>UAT-OTA-2010B</ns3:ReferenceVersion>
                  </ns3:Document>
               </ns3:OrderViewRS>
            </NDCMSG_Payload>
         </NDCMSG_Body>
      </ns2:NDCMSG_Envelope>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

You may want to make the property transfer as a Groovy Script teststep, using XML Slurper. It could go something like this:

```
def xml = context.expand( '${TestStepName#Response}' )
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(xml)
def response = new XmlSlurper().parseText(holder.getXml())
def value = response.Body.NDCMSG_Envelope.NDCMSG_Body.NDCMSG_Payload.OrderViewRS.Document.Name
return value
```

Thereby circumventing the namespace problem. The result from this teststep should be easy to transfer.